# How to prevent my Steam from messing with my outside audio?

Tags: steam

Imagine me, sitting there at my computer watching a YouTube video. While I am sitting there, a friend of me messages me. Steam, trying to be the considerate person, lowers the volume of my video. I reach over to the volume slider, and move it back up. Seconds later though, as my friend messages me, Steam pulls the slider back down to a lower level. I tried looking around in the settings, but there was nothing about prevent it from altering my audio. Is there a way, and if so, how?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a windows audio thing. I had a similar problem with Skype. Can you try [this fix](http://www.askvg.com/fix-windows-7-automatically-reduces-system-volume-for-games-pc-calls/)?

Comment: That seemed to be the problem, thanks for helping me (sowwy steam), you can post that as an answer.

Comment: It's not Steam, it's Windows; see [Windows 7 lowers application volume automatically](http://superuser.com/questions/74116/windows-7-lowers-applications-volume-automatically)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a windows feature which can cause issues with a number of gaming applications e.g. Steam and Teamspeak. Fortunately there's an easy way to turn it off:

1. Go to your Windows Control Panel
2. Sound
3. Communications tab
4. Where it says "When Windows detects communications activity:", Select "Do Nothing"

[image: Do nothing]

Windows automatically partially mutes other applications when it detects what it thinks of as a phone call.